# android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView (android-studio)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

Im Trying To paste data(from an Intent) on a customized ListView ,and then I get this error,but when I did it with an uncustomized ListView it worked properly.
I understood that the problem occurs when I change :

```
ListAdapter theAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,timegone);
```

to:

```
 ListAdapter theAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_layout,timegone);
```

But I dont get why it doesnt work!

Here below I added the row_layout.xml file which Causes  the app crash.

Thats how it **works** :

```
public class Shifts extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.shifts);
    Intent MyIntent=getIntent();
    String timepass=MyIntent.getExtras().getString("time");

    ListView thelist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
   String[] timegone=timepass.split(":");
    ListAdapter theAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,**android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1**,timegone);

    thelist.setAdapter(theAdapter);


    }

}
```

And thats how it **doesnt work**:

```
public class Shifts extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.shifts);
    Intent MyIntent=getIntent();
    String timepass=MyIntent.getExtras().getString("time");

    ListView thelist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
   String[] timegone=timepass.split(":");
    ListAdapter theAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,**R.layout.row_layout**,timegone);

    thelist.setAdapter(theAdapter);


    }
}
```

This is the row_layout.xml that im using in the adapter

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainScreen"
android:id="@+id/ly"

>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="15dp"/>

     </LinearLayout>
```

What should I do in order to fix this ?
Thank you!

Comment: you need to create custom adapter for your custom row...

Comment: The TextView has to have ID `@android:id/text1`. Or remove the LinearLayout, because it's useless, it has just one child element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom adapter if you want custom layout of list row..

[here](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92) you can see the example.